# How does Kubernetes 1.26 (minikube 1.30.1) runs on Docker 20.10.23 if Dockershim has been removed from 1.24?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I heard that Dockershim has been removed from Kubernetes 1.24. I have not used minikube for a while as I was using kind and k3s. But right now I see Minikube 1.30.1 says starting k8s 1.26 on kvm VM using docker 20.10.23. How is this possible?

Comment: Take a look here: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dockershim-faq/#can-i-still-use-dockershim-after-it-is-removed-from-kubernetes ; https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/migrating-from-dockershim/check-if-dockershim-removal-affects-you/

Answer (score 2):

As per the [official doc](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2022/02/17/dockershim-faq/), dockershim was deprecated and you can use CRI (Container Run Time) as an interface to docker instead of dockershim. CRI-compatible runtimes like containerd and CRI-O are already being used and supported hence it has become the recommended way to run Docker with Kubernetes.

As mentioned in official docs you can also use another tool that support dockershim :

> ```
> Is there any tooling that can help me find dockershim in use?
>
> Yes! The Detector for Docker Socket (DDS) is a kubectl plugin that you can install and then use to check your cluster.
> DDS can detect if active Kubernetes workloads are mounting the Docker Engine socket (docker.sock) as a volume.
> ```

Link for: [Detector for Docker Socket (DDS)](https://github.com/aws-containers/kubectl-detector-for-docker-socket)